# multiple json outputs from single render acion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, fullcalendar

I have controller action where I want json output to have a series of variables for fullcalendar.

#### the as_json method is model is as follows

```
def as_json(options = {})
  ((self.start_at).to_date..(self.end_at).to_date).each do |m|
   {
     :id => self.id,
     :title => self.subject,
     :description => self.category.category_name || "",
     :start => (self.start_at.to_datetime + i++).rfc822,
     :end => ((self.duration.minutes.since self.start_at).to_datetime + i++).rfc822,
     :allDay => false,#self.all_day,
     :recurring => false,
     :url => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.conference_path(id),
     #:color => "red"
   } 
  end
end
```

but it throws json_encode error.

also i tried to loop in the controller to render multiple json with different values but only one json response can be created. How can i achieve my goal to have multiple json response?

#### Current Json response

```
[{"id":17,"title":"ki mas","description":"Rails","start":"Wed, 2 Apr 2014 01:00:00 +0000","end":"Wed, 2 Apr 2014 02:00:00 +0000","allDay":false,"recurring":false,"url":"/conferences/17"}]
```

#### But i need something like this form one response or anything to achieve following output

```
[{"id":17,"title":"ki mas","description":"Rails","start":"Wed, 2 Apr 2014 01:00:00 +0000","end":"Wed, 2 Apr 2014 02:00:00 +0000","allDay":false,"recurring":false,"url":"/conferences/17"}]
[{"id":17,"title":"ki mas","description":"Rails","start":"Thurs, 3 Apr 2014 01:00:00 +0000","end":"Thurs, 3 Apr 2014 02:00:00 +0000","allDay":false,"recurring":false,"url":"/conferences/17"}]
[{"id":17,"title":"ki mas","description":"Rails","start":"Fri, 4 Apr 2014 01:00:00 +0000","end":"Fri, 4 Apr 2014 02:00:00 +0000","allDay":false,"recurring":false,"url":"/conferences/17"}]
[{"id":17,"title":"ki mas","description":"Rails","start":"Sat, 5 Apr 2014 01:00:00 +0000","end":"Sat, 5 Apr 2014 02:00:00 +0000","allDay":false,"recurring":false,"url":"/conferences/17"}]
....
```

and so on..
Please help me achieve this.

Comment: Are you trying to build an API?

Comment: Not exactly. Trying to feed fullcalendar plugin appropriate inputs as json objects to achieve recurring events marking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple... :) You just have to manage server side to output this format...

```
[{"id":17,"title":"ki mas","description":"Rails","start":"Wed, 2 Apr 2014 01:00:00  +0000","end":"Wed, 2 Apr 2014 02:00:00 +0000","allDay":false,"recurring":false,"url":"/conferences/17"},
{"id":17,"title":"ki mas","description":"Rails","start":"Thurs, 3 Apr 2014 01:00:00 +0000","end":"Thurs, 3 Apr 2014 02:00:00 +0000","allDay":false,"recurring":false,"url":"/conferences/17"},
{"id":17,"title":"ki mas","description":"Rails","start":"Fri, 4 Apr 2014 01:00:00 +0000","end":"Fri, 4 Apr 2014 02:00:00 +0000","allDay":false,"recurring":false,"url":"/conferences/17"},
{"id":17,"title":"ki mas","description":"Rails","start":"Sat, 5 Apr 2014 01:00:00      +0000","end":"Sat, 5 Apr 2014 02:00:00      +0000","allDay":false,"recurring":false,"url":"/conferences/17"}]
```